# Can't change hover color on bootstrap 4 navbar-brand class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is the  code

```css
.navbar-brand a:hover {
  color: #43cea2 !important;
}
```

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#about">Cole Caccamise</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using inline style?
This isn't always the best solution but usually works for me

You could also add a custom class or Id to the element

Comment: Tanner, inline style may be easier but difficult to maintain, better practice writing external style sheet . Please be specific on your  question

Comment: You're right that it's worse to maintain, that's why I'd suggest a custom class in addition to the navbar-brand class

Comment: write external css, so that u can reuse the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-brand a{
 color: #43cea2;
}
```

This means Select any anchor(a) element that is a child of any element with a class name of "navbar-brand".

you need to use-

```
a.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #43cea2;
}
```

you can read more here:
https://css-tricks.com/whats-the-difference/